# CSS Style for icons does not follow table child

Tags: html, css

I have a simple table cell that contains texts and icons. The table follows different colors in 2 specific moments. First when the table is created and the child even rows get gray color. Second, when I hover over. I want all the time to have same background color for the icons as shown on the row background color of the table.

```
/* Table CSS references */
#tabelarelat {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    display:table;
}

#tabelarelat td, #tabelarelat th {
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    padding: 6px;
}

#tabelarelat tr:nth-child(even){ 
          background-color: #f2f2f2;
}

/* Button Icons */
.btnicoUC {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 8px 8px;
  font-size: 14px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.btnicoUC:hover {
  background-color: #fcebcd;
}
```

[Table with different line colors and icons does not following it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MIYB7.png)

If i remove :

```
.btnicoUC {
  background-color: #ffffff;  <--- This line
  border: none;
  (...)
```

Also does not work.

This part of the code:

```
.btnicoUC:hover {
  background-color: #fcebcd;
}
```

Works only when the mouse is over the Icon.

I tried also some thing like:

```
#tabelarelat > tr > :nth-child(even) > btnicoUC { 
          background-color: #f2f2f2;
}
```

But doesent work. Thanks in advance.

----- HTML code:

```
<table id="tabelarelat">
<tr><th colspan=2>TITLE</th></tr>
<tr><th style="width:80px"></th>
<th>ID</th></tr>
<tr><td align='center'><form action="#bottom" method="post">       
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="idvalue">
<button class="btnicoUC" name="submitI" type="submit"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i></button>
<button class="btnicoUC" name="submitI" type="submit"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></button>
</form></td><td> 1000 </td></tr>
<tr><td align='center'><form action="#bottom" method="post">       
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="idvalue">
<button class="btnicoUC" name="submitI" type="submit"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i></button>
<button class="btnicoUC" name="submitI" type="submit"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></button>
</form></td><td> 1001 </td></tr>
<tr><td align='center'><form action="#bottom" method="post">       
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="idvalue">
<button class="btnicoUC" name="submitI" type="submit"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i></button>
<button class="btnicoUC" name="submitI" type="submit"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></button>
</form></td><td> 1002 </td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: use `position relative` and `z-index`

Comment: @RayeesAC If you have an answer, post it below.

Comment: Please show your html - see [mcve]

Comment: The `position relative` or `z-index` does not work. The HTML is added to the original code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

Edits:

- **change all even tr background to #f2f2f2**

```
#tabelarelat  tr:nth-child(even) .btnicoUC {
   background-color: #f2f2f2;       
}
```

- **change all odd background to #fff**

```
#tabelarelat  tr:nth-child(odd) .btnicoUC {
   background-color: #fff;
}
```

- **change hover the icon background to #fcebcd**

```
#tabelarelat tr:hover .btnicoUC {background-color: #fcebcd;}
```

- **change hover the tr background to #fcebcd**

```
#tabelarelat tr:hover {background-color: #fcebcd;}
```

**Live Demo**

```css
/* Table CSS references */
#tabelarelat {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    display:table;
}

#tabelarelat td, #tabelarelat th {
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    padding: 6px;
}

#tabelarelat tr:nth-child(even){ 
          background-color: #f2f2f2;
}

/* Button Icons */
.btnicoUC {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 8px 8px;
  font-size: 14px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#tabelarelat  tr:nth-child(even) .btnicoUC {
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
}

#tabelarelat  tr:nth-child(odd) .btnicoUC {
  background-color: #fff;
}

#tabelarelat tr:hover .btnicoUC {background-color: #fcebcd;}

#tabelarelat tr:hover {background-color: #fcebcd;}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<table id="tabelarelat">
<tr><th colspan=2>TITLE</th></tr>
<tr><th style="width:80px"></th>
<th>ID</th></tr>
<tr><td align='center'><form action="#bottom" method="post">       
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="idvalue">
<button class="btnicoUC" name="submitI" type="submit"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i></button>
<button class="btnicoUC" name="submitI" type="submit"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></button>
</form></td><td> 1000 </td></tr>
<tr><td align='center'><form action="#bottom" method="post">       
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="idvalue">
<button class="btnicoUC" name="submitI" type="submit"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i></button>
<button class="btnicoUC" name="submitI" type="submit"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></button>
</form></td><td> 1001 </td></tr>
<tr><td align='center'><form action="#bottom" method="post">       
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="idvalue">
<button class="btnicoUC" name="submitI" type="submit"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i></button>
<button class="btnicoUC" name="submitI" type="submit"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></button>
</form></td><td> 1002 </td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Are you something like this? if any changes i would happy to change the answer too. Thanks  :)

Comment: I change the code with this code: `#tabelarelat  tr:nth-child(even) .btnicoUC { 
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
}

#tabelarelat  tr:nth-child(odd) .btnicoUC { 
  background-color: #fff;
}` and almost worked. By this way keep the colors Gray and White for each line. The problem  now is when I hover with the mouse over the line.

Comment: Completed with this code: `#tabelarelat tr:hover .btnicoUC {background-color: #fcebcd;}`

Comment: Just to complete the text, was missed the followed item: `#tabelarelat tr:hover {background-color: #fcebcd;}` Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think the css rule you are looking for is this one:

```
#tabelarelat  tr:nth-child(even) .btnicoUC { 
          background-color: #f2f2f2;
}
```

it puts gray background to the icons placed in even rows